# Running node.js app and getting angular is not defined message

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I am trying to run an app in node.js and I've never used node before, when I enter node app.js into terminal, I get this error message:

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michael/Desktop/myapp/app/app.js:20:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:508:3
```

I installed angular. Here is the section of code for the app.js file that is mentioned in the error:

```
var app = angular
.module('gbook', ['ui.router', 'uiSwitch', 'LocalStorageModule', 'vsGoogleAutocomplete', 'ngCookies', 'gbook.config', 'gbook.intlTelInput', 'ui.timepicker', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'froala', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(config)
.run(run);
```

I also have this code in index.js under the angular folder:

```
require('./angular');
module.exports = angular;
```

Did I do something wrong installing angular, or is it something else?

Comment: Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Angular is client-side framework and Node is server-side. Why would you want to run angular in node? (It is possible to run Angular app with Node.js backed but what you are doing is different and seems wrong)

Comment: plz check your libraries are kept in public folder so that they are loading properly in browser

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use angular on server side. Angular is used for client side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use angular in server side, however you could use a render engine like ejs or jade with express and use angular in a .ejs file. This way you can also have access to variables used on your backend. I suggest googling expressjs and ejs and doing a bit of research on it.

One more thing, make sure your AngularJS is hooked properly on your frontend either through a cdn or JavaScript files.